# QHeaderView has no horizontal lines in Windows 10

Tags: qt, windows-10, qtablewidget, qheaderview

[image]

`QTableWidget` headers have no horizontal lines in Windows 10. How can I fix it?

Comment: @Ankur's stylesheet solution works, but in this case Windows 10 style disappeared. Are there any more solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. It can be solved with the following style sheet on the table view/widget:

```
if(QSysInfo::windowsVersion()==QSysInfo::WV_WINDOWS10){
    setStyleSheet(
        "QHeaderView::section{"
            "border-top:0px solid #D8D8D8;"
            "border-left:0px solid #D8D8D8;"
            "border-right:1px solid #D8D8D8;"
            "border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8;"
            "background-color:white;"
            "padding:4px;"
        "}"
        "QTableCornerButton::section{"
            "border-top:0px solid #D8D8D8;"
            "border-left:0px solid #D8D8D8;"
            "border-right:1px solid #D8D8D8;"
            "border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8;"
            "background-color:white;"
        "}");}
```

This is C++ code but it should be easy to adapt to your needs.

Note1: The background-color and padding are unfortunate but they are necessary to make our custom rendering looks like the default one.

Note2: The color of the border is the color of the grid on my system. I did not use the color of the default header.

Note3: The `QTableCornerButton::section` part is necessary to add the missing border below the top left corner. If the vertical header is not visible, the missing line is invisible too.

Note4: If (like me) you find that the ugly grey rectangle below the name of your rows needs fixing, just add `QHeaderView{background-color:white;}` to your style sheet.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

set this stylesheet in tablewidget.

```
QTableWidget ::section {
   border: 1px outset #161618;
}
```

Comment: It works. But somewhere width is 1px and somewhere is 2px. Can I make same widths? https://i.imgur.com/GLiE9TC.png?1

Comment: Try this: 
QTableWidget ::section {
   border-top: 0px solid #161618;
  border-left: 0px solid #161618;
  border-right: 1px solid #161618;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #161618;
}

Comment: Thanks! It is much more better than without lines. Now I will try to find solution for keeping Windows 10 headers style but with horizontal lines.

Comment: @ Ankur maybe you know solution how to add line here https://i.imgur.com/WdAX4Oa.png?1 ?

Comment: @Ufx , try this QTableView#tableWidget QHeaderView
{
    border-top: 0px solid #161618;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #161618;
}

Comment: @ Ankur is it possible to make without these lines https://i.imgur.com/3zWzI30.png ?